# mcrypt function works on old server not on new

Tags: php, encryption

We have some legacy needs to use a mcrypt decode function.

- old sever Ubuntu Linux 10.04.1 [working sample](http://pcsmarts.biz/tec.php). There is an info.php available
- new server Debian Linux 8 [failing sample](https://alfa.pcsmarts.biz/tec.php). There is an info.php available

PHP Version 5.6.14-0+deb8u1 on both servers.

PHP code:

```
<?php

  $salt = '5@Fuv}7F^LkC[k_bx~E^'; // 
  $text = 'Our text decoeded';
  $encout = simple_encrypt($salt, $text);
  echo 'encrypted: ' . $encout .'<br/>';
  echo 'decrypted: ' . simple_decrypt($salt, $encout) ;


  function simple_encrypt($salt, $text) {   
    return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
  }

  function simple_decrypt($salt, $text)
  {
    return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt,       base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
  }
?>
```

Why would these two serves be different?

Comment: Also, this encryption code is VERY insecure. [ECB mode](https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin/), [MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because previously, mcrypt would accept non-standard key or iv sizes and simply pad them with \0 until they were the correct length. As of 5.6 (your old server is not running 5.6, it seems to be running 5.3), as you can see in the docs, invalid keys and ivs are no longer accepted and mcrypt_encrypt fails. Your key seems to be 160 bits long and it needs to be 192 bits (the next valid key length). You can fix it by appending 4 \0s to your key.

Comment: I would think that it pads with four 0x00 bytes to reach a valid key size: 192 bit.

Comment: 192 bits is not a valid key size for a 256 bit keyed cipher such as MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256.

Comment: The 256 in `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` means the block size. Rijndael supports three block sizes and three key sizes independently. Perhaps you mixed up Rijndael and AES. AES is a subset of Rijndael with a fixed block size of 128 bit.

Comment: No, I didn't mix them up, I just got it wrong. Putting the key size there is pretty typical everywhere else (say, TLS bulk cipher suite descriptors). I guess they put the block size there because of the awful, silently-null-padding previous interface. I'll fix up the answer in a bit.